# Implement a follow system using Ajax, MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, twitter

I was trying to implement a Twitter like follow system using this tutorial: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/04/exactly-twitter-like-follow-and-remove.html

For my database, I would require two variables:
current_user:the username of the user who is currently logged in
profile_user:the username of the user whose profile has been visited

Now, every profile has an url like this:
profile.php?user_username=aaa&current_user=bbb

Here, user_username:the username of the user whose profile has been visited, i.e. profile_user
current_user:the username of the user who is currently logged in

What I want to achieve is that when the current_user clicks on a button, which, by default, says 'Follow', there will be an entry in the database, the structure of which is like this:
follow_current_user: which stores the username of the current_user
follow_profile_user: which stores the username of the profile_user

For the body structure, I've followed the tutorial (http://www.9lessons.info/2009/04/exactly-twitter-like-follow-and-remove.html) thoroughly but couldn't implement properly. Any help please?

Further information:
The user database is like the following:
user_id
user_username
user_password

Answer (score 0):

**When user clicks the follow button make a form with empty fields and send it to another page there receive all the fields and insert them into table.**

Actually  this system is hard to implement first of all make a plan on paper that what will happen when a user will click button on another users profile. First of all do it with PHP do not use Ajax. When you will master this problem then you will be able to do it in any way.